# Getting file name with second largest number in it when the numbers are same

Tags: node.js

I was trying to get file name in which is second largest number and it always outputs the file with largest number. What am I doing wrong? 
Example: I have 3 file names in which are stored numbers like: 6 or 6 or 1 and it always outputs first file name with number 6 in it. I need to output the file name with second number 6.

```
const getSecondFileName = (pathToFolder) => {
      const files = fs.readdirSync(pathToFolder);
      const content = files.map(f => +fs.readFileSync(`${pathToFolder}/${f}`, 'UTF-8'));
      const arrayCopy = [...content];
      const secondLargestNum = arrayCopy.sort()[arrayCopy.length - 2]
      const secondFileWithLargestInteger = files[content.indexOf(secondLargestNum)];

      return secondFileWithLargestInteger;        
    }
```

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: when using sort be aware that sort convert array's element to string 
const array1 = [6, 40, 7, 21];
array1.sort(); ======> output will be Array [21, 40, 6, 7]

Comment: and here second large num file and first large num file contain same value you ended up with specific case that you should handle separately

Comment: So what do you recommand?

Comment: i suggest an answer below, let me know if you want more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since indexOf returns the first occurrence and you're firstLargestNum and secondLargestNum are the same (wich is a special case), let's handle it apart

```
 const getSecondFileName = (pathToFolder) => {
      let secondFileWithLargestInteger;
      const files = fs.readdirSync(pathToFolder);
      const arrLength = files.length;
      const content = files.map(f => +fs.readFileSync(`${pathToFolder}/${f}`, 'UTF-8'));
      const arrayCopy = [...content];
      const sortedArray = arrayCopy.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;
      });;
      const firstLargestNum = sortedArray[arrLength- 1];
      const secondLargestNum = sortedArray[arrLength- 2];
      if (firstLargestNum === secondLargestNum) {
        const indexofFirst = content.indexOf(secondLargestNum);
        // const indexofFirst = content.indexOf(firstLargestNum); same 
        secondFileWithLargestInteger = files[content.indexOf(secondLargestNum, (indexofFirst + 1))]
      } else {
        secondFileWithLargestInteger = files[content.indexOf(secondLargestNum)];
      }
      return secondFileWithLargestInteger;        
    }
```

I'm using a different method than yours here to sort, because element in your files are string.

```
var numbers = ['1', '5', '12', '3', '7', '15', '9']; 
// Sorting the numbers array simply using the sort method
numbers.sort(); // Sorts numbers array
alert(numbers); // Outputs: 1,12,15,3,5,7,9
```

Sort method sorts the array elements alphabetically

Comment: Nice post but it always inputs random file if I add file or delete file it is always different

Comment: just found out if it is double digit number makes it go crazy, even with my code Do you know why?

Comment: with double digit if you use above suggestion to sort, you'll be safe see this link https://alligator.io/js/array-sort-numbers/

Comment: i update the code, your right it wasn't working, let's give it a try now please

Comment: Thanks will look at it tomorrow :) In your code it is not implemented the sort thing?

Comment: it's implemented const sortedArray = arrayCopy.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b;});;